# Access denied on CreateFileMapping when run under different user accounts with runas

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-xp, file-mapping

This code gives me access denied errors when trying to open previously created file mapping. Help, help, help.

- OS: WinXP SP3, no fast user switching.
- Following code is run on 2 different user accounts using runas.
- Both users have Administrator privileges.

test code:

```
SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;

if(!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
    printf("InitializeSecurityDescriptor failed %d\n", GetLastError());

if(!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, true, 0, false))
    printf("SetSecurityDescriptorDacl failed %d\n", GetLastError());

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = &sd;
sa.bInheritHandle = false;

HANDLE hMap = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0x1000, "Global\\MyMap");
void* pMap = 0;
if(hMap) {
    pMap = MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0x1000);
} else {
    printf("CreateFileMapping failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    hMap = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, false, "Global\\MyMap");
    if(hMap) {
        printf("OpenFileMapping sucess!\n");
    } else {
        printf("OpenFileMapping failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
}
if(pMap) {
    printf("Sucess!\n");
    printf("DW: %X", *(DWORD*)pMap);
    *(DWORD*)pMap = 0xDEADBEEF;
} else {
    printf("MapViewOfFile failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
}

cin.ignore();

if(pMap)
    UnmapViewOfFile(pMap);

if(hMap)
    CloseHandle(hMap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES struct to CreateFileMapping...